# How to make Ionic 2 App Faster?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been working on an Ionic 2 App, which is slower in loading a page(from one page to another). From Chrome Dev Tools, I recorded the timeline of page transition and saw that the Maximum time is taking for RENDERING. Yes, the app has some complicated html views, but not complicated as compared to the rendering time.

Can anyone please suggest me some tips to make RENDERING faster? I've tried building in '--prod' mode also, Its taking the same time.  If disabling page transition helps, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: did you test this on real device?

Comment: yes. I tried on Redmi note 3 (3 GB RAM). Its not that fast as compared to other ionic Apps

Comment: what type of application you're developing? What about backend services? 3rd part Api calls and etc?

Comment: It's much of API calls to our server

Comment: The app is an interface to our hardware

Comment: You can see that no.Now the problem is not on Ionic2 views.it's due to your API calls.So you must optimize it for a mobile app.Try to test the app without API calls (do a light weight mock) and see the difference.

Comment: Yes,  I already did that. I found no problem with API calls..

Comment: And I also tried increasing the data in list view... The time taken for rendering is growing much faster than that of scripting, api etc

Comment: Ok, then put an issue on Ionic git repo with the working sample (plunker): https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/new

Comment: That, Ill do. Do you know how to disable page transition animations?

Answer (score 3):

One option would be the ***disable page transition animations***.You can do that as shown below.Hope that will increase the page loading time.

*app.module.ts*

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { animate: false })
  ],
```

Comment: Did it @ChaitanyaMankala ?

Comment: not considerably. Anyways, I would not prefer this @tjvg1991